# Conditional subscriptions with Guava EventBus

Tags: java, guava

I am looking at using the [Guava EventBus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) in my application to distribute data (`Double`s for example) from one or more data creators through to data consumer.

I know in my consumer class, I need to annotate my data handler with `@Subscribe`. Is there a way in which to make this subscription conditional? So for example

```
@Subscribe {newValue > 0.0} public void valueUpdated(Double newValue)
```

I could add the check within my `valueUpdated` method, but is there a way to stop the `EventBus` from dispatching values that my Subscriber is not interested in?

Is there a product similar to EventBus that may provide this sort of function?

Comment: I don't see a significant advantage of having a DSL for conditional dispatch over that same condition being the first sentence in the handler. In fact, the DSL would likely be slower by a large margin.

Comment: @U Mad - Thank you for your comment. I have a use case where I could have a large number of subscribers. In this case, I thought it may be more efficient to have conditional dispatch. Though I agree that having the condition in the handler makes things simpler.

Comment: I don't think you can gain any speed up here, at least not without thousands subscribers and/or a slowdown for the common unconditional  case. Written like `{newValue > 0.0}` it'd need an interpreter and it'll cost probably more than a few hundreds trivial tests in your code. Written like `MyPositiveDoublePredicate.class` it could be much faster, but not especially convenient. And in any case it'd impose some cost on the normal subscribers.

Comment: There's no possible way conditional dispatch could be more efficient.  Just check it in the subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) may help.

Plus: after checking the EventBus, I think it's **type-based** dispatch, no way to apply condition-based dispatch. If you insist on using Expression Language, you could put it in subscriber as Louis comment. But Expression Language is designed for flexibility rather than speed.

Comment: @Shengyuan Lu - thank you for your answer. Could you give me an example on how SpEL may be used in this context?

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve this using with [Guava EventBus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) using your own Dispatcher implementation where you dispatch an event of type MyEvent only if it is interesting i.e. its newValue is greater than 0.

```
package com.google.common.eventbus;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors;
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.Iterator;
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

public class MyDispatcher extends Dispatcher {

    private static final MyDispatcher INSTANCE = new MyDispatcher();

    @Override
    void dispatch(Object event, Iterator<Subscriber> subscribers) {
        checkNotNull(event);
        if (event instanceof MyEvent) {
            Double newValue = ((MyEvent) event).getNewValue();
            if (null != newValue && newValue > 0.0d) { //dispatch events only if newValue > 0.0d
                while (subscribers.hasNext()) {
                    subscribers.next().dispatchEvent(event);
                }
            }
        } else {
            while (subscribers.hasNext()) {
                subscribers.next().dispatchEvent(event);
            }
        }
    }

    @Data
    public static class MyEvent {
        private Object sender;
        private Double newValue;
    }

    public static class MyEventBus extends EventBus {
        public MyEventBus() {
            super("myEventBys", MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService(), MyDispatcher.INSTANCE,
                LoggingHandler.INSTANCE);
        }
    }
}
```